# How make server response on different sub-domains using web xml

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web.xml, apache-tomee

Let's say i've a lot of different of sub-domains ,

I want to redirect each request to the server so it will response with different action on each request of sub-domain
(with text or html generated on server)

I'm working with EJB 3.1 on Tomcat 7 using web.xml , and I want to use with only one webapp

## Example:

```
http://companyName1.mycompany.com

responce to client: "hello aaa companyName1 ..."


http://companyName2.mycompany.com

responce to client: "hello bbb companyName2 ..."

http://companyName3.mycompany.com

responce to client: "hello ccc companyName3 ..."
```

What is correct web.xml or server.xml mapping to solve this issue ??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You want server.xml, not web.xml.  Add an alias for each subdomain in the appropriate Host block.

So you would have something like this:

```
<Host name="mycompany.com" appBase="webapps" ... >
  <Alias>companyName1.mycompany.com</Alias>
  <Alias>companyName2.mycompany.com</Alias>
  <Alias>companyName3.mycompany.com</Alias>
  ...
</Host>
```

Then use `request.getServerName()` to determine the subdomain.

Comment: MarkOlsson: Thanks I'll check it , but what is the mapping of the servlet i should use for that ?

Comment: If I want to test it locally first , is this server.xml correct ??           <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Context path="" docBase="ROOT" debug="0" reloadable="true"></Context>
      
      <Alias>honeybook.localhost</Alias>
       <Alias>facebook.localhost</Alias>
   
      </Host>

Comment: The servlet mapping is independent of the host mapping.  The domain and alias domains from a Host will be sent to the app designated by the appBase.  In other words, I don't think you can't map servlets in one webapp to multiple subdomains.  So all requests to companyName*.mycompany.com all go to the same servlets.  You'll have to compare the return value of request.getServetName() to decide which company to process.

Comment: I don't know if `xxxxx.localhost` will work or not, you'll have to try it.  Personally, I use the hosts file to redirect internally used names to localhost so I can use the name instead of IP address or "localhost".

Comment: As you wrote "So all requests to companyName*.mycompany.com all go to the same servlets" , how could I know to which servlet ? I just want print the  request.getServerName() , and don't understand how , I have "<Context path="" docBase="ROOT" debug="0" reloadable="true">" , so all requests would mapped into ROOT webapp , to which servlet ? :)

Comment: Oh, that's a very different question.  Google "servlet tutorial" and start from the beginning.

Comment: I know the basics concepts, all the examples of servlets including url mapping with prefix/suffix...as i asked before I need to "make decision" on root servlet whithout any url prefixes as my example the request: --> http://companyName1.mycompany.com has no any prefixes like: http://companyName1.mycompany.com/foo. so i stuck a little with the mapping of xml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118789/discussion-between-vitaly-tarasiuk-and-mark-olsson).

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer regarding `server.xml` will definitely work, but requires a restart every time you need to add/modify it.

Another way would be to keep the standard server.xml, but use `request.getServerName()` to examine hostname the user used to access your server.